# Why Spring MVC configuration support for XML configuration is deprecated?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, struts2

Spring MVC uses mainly annotations to configure its Controllers, as far as I know, the only way to configure a Controller in Spring WITHOUT Annotions (only XML) is extending the AbstracController (or Similar Controller classes) and currently all this classes are deprecated for Spring 3.

While I think that is a good idea to drop support for this classes, mainly because extending this classes creates controllers that hardly depend of Spring as a dependency, I don't understand why Spring doesn't provides a configuration like Struts Actions (Actions in Struts 2 don't extend any weird class so they dont' have any dependency of Struts)

Why Spring MVC doesnt provide a clean POJO-style configuration like Struts 2 Actions via XML?

Why to drop support for XML configuration on MVC using ugly Annotations? why not to drop it in ALL Spring Proyects?

Comment: [This is mostly explained in the _Features_ section of the Spring MVC documentation.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem with the XML/POJO approach is that there is no way to tell from looking at your code that special magic is going on.

Instead of seeing

```
@SomeAnnotation   <<-- Oh, golly there is something special happening here.
java code...
```

You see

```
Java code    <<-- special magic hidden in XML file (or not, no way to tell)
             <<-- are these linked? no idea..
             <<-- is something going on? let me go and search....
```

If changes happen to the source code, the XML may (or may not be) out of sync.

With the annotations you can update the java code and the spring annotations at the same time.
Yes it's cluttered but at least it's easy to sync the two.

Annotations are hard enough to grok when they're in your face. If they're not even visible the mental burden for us non-angry developers is really too much to bear.

> why not to drop it in ALL Spring Projects?

Wouldn't that be sweet....

> using ugly Annotations?

Obviously the question has been asked: [Is there a way to hide annotations in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739009/is-there-a-way-to-hide-annotations-in-netbeans-or-eclipse)
And the answer is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2569646/650492
Sort of... does that help?

Comment: +1 Besides that, there is also the fact that not having to `extends` a framework class leaves your code a little bit more flexible in its own class hierarchy.

Comment: So its safe to say that Spring community is moving from an XML-configuration-to-rule-them-all to an annotations-configuration-to-rule-them-all?